# WSDL validation failure. How to make it valid

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

i have created a small WSDL File, but the validation fails.
The Validator says:

- Service "PortalService" : Port "PortalPort" points to undefined binding
- Message for input element of operation "UpdateKunde" is undefined
- Message for output element of operation "UpdateKunde" is undefined
- Binding "PortalBinding" references undefined PortType

I think the problem must be inside these lines:

```
    <xsd:element name="UpdateKunde">
        <xsd:complexType>
           <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Kunde" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                       <xsd:element name="Lastchange" type="xsd:dateTime" />
                       <xsd:element name="Vorname" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
                       <xsd:element name="Nachname" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />                 
                    </xsd:sequence>
                 </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
           </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>   
     <xsd:element name="UpdateKundeResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
           <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Kunde" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                       <xsd:element name="Kundennummer" type="xsd:unsignedInt" />
                       <xsd:element name="Statuscode" type="xsd:int" />
                       <xsd:element name="Statusbeschreibung" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />   
                    </xsd:sequence>
                 </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
           </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:element>

<wsdl:message name="UpdateKunde">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:UpdateKunde" name="UpdateKunde" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UpdateKundeResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:UpdateKundeResponse" name="UpdateKundeResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="PortalPortType">
  <wsdl:operation name="UpdateKunde">
     <wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateKunde" />
     <wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateKundeResponse" />
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

 <wsdl:binding name="PortalBinding" type="tns:PortalPortType">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <wsdl:operation name="UpdateKunde">
     <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="" />
     <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
     </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PortalService">
  <wsdl:port name="PortalPort" binding="tns:PortalBinding">
     <soap:address location="##########" />
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The soap Address exists, but i am not allowed to show it.
I hope someone have a idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: After some time i had found the solution. The header of my WSDL must have had a problem. With this header everthing works:

<wsdl:definitions name ="SOAP"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tns="<yourdomain>"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:targetNamespace="<yourdomain>/">